# Apply tax alternative

Tags: magento-1.9, tax

If customer zip/post code (123456) has no tax rate define in back-end it is possible to set tax rate of that state ?

Suppose customer selected Newyork and `pin = xyz` but this zip/post has no any tax rate in system, in this case I want to apply max tax rate of Newyork from back end. Is it is possible ?

Comment: By pin code do you mean zip/post code?

Comment: @JakefromTaxJar yes

Answer (score 1):

If you use a wildcard `*` Zip/Post Code when creating a new tax rate for New York under **Sales > Tax > Manage Tax Zones & Rates**, you can use that as catch-all to apply a max tax rate in New York. Make sure **State** is set to `New York` and **Zip/Post Code** is set to `*`.